How do I get a daily average for data points generated every 15 minutes?
This is my first question and I'm also a very new learner to r so please bear with me. I am working on some gauge data from about 4 months and it took temperature readings every 15 minutes. I am wanting to get a daily average from this data and then graph it. I have looked some stuff up and tried to run what people have suggested, but keep running into this error:
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

DownGauge %>% 
+   group_by(day = day(date)) %>%
+   summarise(mean_Temperature = mean(Temperature))
**Error in `group_by()`:
ℹ In argument: `day = day(date)`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.default()`:
! do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”**

Any help would be much appreciated. I am really struggling to find a good answer to this question. I have included the dput and head of my data below because I saw that is good policy to provide. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks.
dput(head(DownGauge))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1709770500, 1709771400, 1709772300, 
1709773200, 1709774100, 1709775000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Temperature = c(8, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

head(DownGauge)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Date                Temperature
  <dttm>                    <dbl>
1 2024-03-07 00:15:00         8  
2 2024-03-07 00:30:00         7.9
3 2024-03-07 00:45:00         7.9
4 2024-03-07 01:00:00         7.9
5 2024-03-07 01:15:00         7.9
6 2024-03-07 01:30:00         7.9`

I tried to change the as.POSIXlt to as.POSIXct cause I thought that would fix it but when I created a new data frame with the changed date format, it just switched automatically back to as.POSIXlt. Not sure why.

List all the non-base R packages that you are using. R is case sensetive. Your column is called Date but you seem to be calling day(date).

Will do. I will edit it. I am using lubridate which has that function. I will add it to my post. Any reason why this would not work using lubridate?

You are interested in grouping the date. ie if you group by day(date) then 1st of every month would be grouped together and thats incorrect. Consider using the following:
DownGauge %>%
   group_by(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
   summarise(mean_temp = mean(Temperature))

# A tibble: 1 × 2
  Date        mean_temp
  <date>          <dbl>
1 2024-03-07       7.92


This worked! Thank you. Do you know why this wouldn't work with what I was doing. I was using lubridate package so day(date) should correlate to the day I believe.

@MattSchaaf I just explained. What you did was grouping the 1st of each month together eg. 1st of january was being grouped together with 1st of february and 1st of march etc

Ok. Sorry it's hard for me to fully understand. I appreciate your help though. You solved my problem.

The United States Geological Survey provides access to their water quality database which includes 15-minute observation of water temperature. Their data can be accessed in R using the dataRetrieval package. Below is an example of how to access 4 months of 15-minute water temperature observations from one gauging station, calculate daily mean, and plot the results.
library(tidyverse)
library(dataRetrieval)

# Download 15-minute water temperature data from U.S. Geological Survey
wtemp <- readNWISuv(
  siteNumbers = '02035000', # USGS site number (Cartersville, VA)
  parameterCd = '00010', # this is the pcode for water temperature
  startDate = '2022-04-01',
  endDate = '2022-08-31',
  tz = 'America/New_York') %>%
  renameNWISColumns()

# Calculate daily mean water temperature
daily_wtemp <- wtemp %>%
  mutate(Date = date(dateTime)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(DailyMean = mean(Wtemp_Inst, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Plot daily mean water temperature
daily_wtemp %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = DailyMean)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = expression(Daily~Mean~Water~Temperature~(degree*C))) +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-06-26 with reprex v2.1.0
